# Is it possible to record Audio in minimized state UWP

Tags: uwp, voice-recording

I need to use voice recording in UWP
**But if App is minimized then recording doesn't work.**

Is there any way to do that, without using restricted capability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ExtendedExecutionSession. It will allow your uwp app to record the audio while minimized. Here is link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution for details. I have tried and it works fine for me.
Add EnteredBackground and LeavingBackground event:

```
        this.EnteredBackground += AppEnteredBackground;
        this.LeavingBackground += AppLeavingBackground;
```

When detecting the event, call BeginExtendedExecution and when session is allowed, call capture audio function.

```
   private async void BeginExtendedExecution()
    {
        ClearExtendedExecution();

        var newSession = new ExtendedExecutionSession();
        newSession.Reason = ExtendedExecutionReason.Unspecified;
        newSession.Description = "recording audio";
        newSession.Revoked += SessionRevoked;
        ExtendedExecutionResult result = await newSession.RequestExtensionAsync();

        switch (result)
        {
            case ExtendedExecutionResult.Allowed:                   
                session = newSession;
                RecordingAudio();

                break;
            default:
            case ExtendedExecutionResult.Denied:                    
                newSession.Dispose();
                break;
        }
       

    }
```

You can take https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/ExtendedExecution/cs/Scenario1_UnspecifiedReason.xaml.cs as example.

Comment: its also restricted capability.

from ms documentation I can see 
"Do not use ExtendedExecutionForegroundSession and ExtendedExecutionForegroundReason; they require restricted capabilities and are not available for use in Store applications."

source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution

Comment: No.It says "Do not use ExtendedExecutionForegroundSession" instead of ExtendedExecutionSession. And ExtendedExecutionSession doesn't need restricted capabilities. In fact, ExtendedExecutionSession is designed for "Run while minimized" which is described in following segment of that link.

Comment: Hi 
if we use this API, 
then voice recording seems muted (no recorded sound) in minimized state. 
Is this behavior expected ?

Comment: I find this also. But if I debug it with a breakpoint, it has data. Interesting. Maybe some MSFT guys could tell why this happens.

Answer (score 2):

Recording audio in the background is a restricted feature.

Here is the way to add restricted capability:

**package.appxmanifest**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package
    ...
    xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
    IgnorableNamespaces="... rescap">
...
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="backgroundMediaRecording"/>
</Capabilities>
</Package>
```

After adding this capability, the application can continue to record audio when minimized.

However, it should be noted that this is a limited capability. If you want to list in the Microsoft Store, you need to provide additional instructions to describe the reason for using this feature.

Thanks.